# OutOfMemoryError в GridPageAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Есть следующее активити. Делаю по этому [туториалу](http://www.learnandroidwear.com/sample-3/). Когда делаю как в примере, с картинками -  все ок, но когда вместо картинок я пытаюсь вставить свои вьюхи получаю  это:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 66 byte allocation with 107972 free bytes and 105KB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 4096 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 0 bytes)
                                                         at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:340)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
                                                         at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                         at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

my_activity.class

```
public class SimpleGridActivity extends WearableActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
        final Resources res = getResources();
        final GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //---Assigns an adapter to provide the content for this pager---
        pager.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
        dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {
        final Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(final Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount(int i) {
            return 2;
        }

        //---Go to current column when scrolling up or down (instead of default column 0)---
        @Override
        public int getCurrentColumnForRow(int row, int currentColumn) {
            return currentColumn;
        }

        //---Return our car image based on the provided row and column---
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int col) {

                ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_check, viewGroup);

                final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) rootView.findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);

                stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                        ((TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView_top_word)).setText("Title");
                        ((TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView_bottom_word)).setText("Description");
                    }
                });
                viewGroup.addView(rootView);
                return rootView;


        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i, int i2, Object o) {
            viewGroup.removeView((View) o);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return view.equals(o);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

При чем если в коде  таким образом создаю - то все работает, а когда инфлейчу xml - то нет:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int col) {

        Button rootView = new Button(mContext);
        rootView.setText("Button Text");
        viewGroup.addView(rootView);
        return rootView;
```